# Straight line when running the Kalman Filter in R

Tags: r, time-series, kalman-filter

I've been following instructions on how to use the Kalman filter and came across the following code which uses the Nile data and produces a plot.

`model_Nile <- SSModel(Nile ~ SSMtrend(1, Q = list(matrix(NA))), H = matrix(NA))
 model_Nile <- fitSSM(model_Nile, c(log(var(Nile)), log(var(Nile))), method = "BFGS")$model
 out_Nile <- KFS(model_Nile, filtering = "state", smoothing = "state")
 conf_Nile <- predict(model_Nile, interval = "confidence", level = 0.9)
 pred_Nile <- predict(model_Nile, interval = "prediction", level = 0.9)
 ts.plot(cbind(Nile, pred_Nile, conf_Nile[, -1]), col = c(1:2, 3, 3, 4, 4), ylab = "Predicted Annual flow", main = "Nile")`

[image]

However, if I replace the Nile data with some other data:

`Nile <- ts(c(1.60,  1.24,  0.87,  0.89,  0.80,  0.30,  0.34,  0.49,  0.11,  0.22,  0.10, -0.11, -0.68, -0.27,  0.67,  0.65,  0.06,  0.17,  0.12, 0.29,  0.60,  0.02,  0.43,  0.36,  0.37,  0.09, -0.16, -0.36,  0.16,  0.41, -0.04,  0.15, -0.74, -0.66, -0.48,  0.10, -0.73, -0.55, -0.78, -0.42, -0.32, -0.67, -0.32, -0.68,  0.34,  0.56,  0.38, -0.11,  0.08,  0.40,  0.27,  0.36,  0.22,  0.30,  0.40,  0.65,  0.24, 0.01, -0.02,  0.27,  0.54,  0.27,  0.32,  0.48,  0.39,  0.42,  0.18,  0.15,  0.10, -0.02,  0.78,  0.48,  0.50,  0.55,  1.14,  0.47, 0.43,  0.55,  1.32,  1.19,  1.63,  2.17,  1.37,  1.03,  0.55,  0.69,  0.04,  0.15, -0.55, -0.70, -1.37, -0.96, -1.33, -1.98, -2.01, -2.00, -1.69, -2.00, -1.28, -1.30, -0.10, -0.18,  0.03, -0.08, -0.03,  0.16,  0.22,  0.28,  0.00,  0.04,  0.33,  0.44,  0.10,  0.21, 0.06, -0.05,  0.95,  0.88,  0.94,  0.95,  0.92,  1.00,  1.06,  1.15,  1.16,  1.10,  1.11,  1.11,  0.90,  0.97,  0.64,  0.61,  0.35, 0.48,  0.39, -0.10, -0.10, -0.04, -0.02, -0.21, -0.39, -0.77, -0.65, -0.82, -0.59, -0.80, -1.05, -0.97, -1.25, -1.25, -1.15, -1.00, -0.97, -0.73, -0.55, -0.75, -1.12, -0.89, -0.31, -0.67, -0.30, -0.33, -0.18, -0.40, -0.64, -0.57, -0.64, -0.60, -0.54,  -0.88, -1.06, -1.26, -1.19, -1.05))`

I get a straight line estimated after running the same above code:
[image]

I don't understand why this is. Could someone please explain.

edit: I have found that multiplying the series by 1000 yields some proper results. Could someone explain why this is?

Comment: Your model has not converged. Check the convergence flag (`$optim.out$par`) and the converged parameter values (`$optim.out$convergence`).

Comment: @tchakravarty parameter values exist (some negative values) and the convergence value is equal to 0 - meaning series does converge?

Comment: Please check those values carefully -- they are the same as your initial values.

Comment: @tchakravarty Sorry, please could you clarify what you mean by initial values?  `model_Nile$optim.out$par
[1] -35.42932 -45.31288`

Comment: Initial values are the second argument to `fitSSM` -- they are the values at which the opitmizer is initialized. In your case: `c(log(var(Nile)), log(var(Nile)))` for the second dataset is: `[1] -0.5336408 -0.5336408`, which is exactly the same as `fitSSM(model_Nile, c(log(var(Nile)), log(var(Nile))), method = "BFGS")$optim.out$par` -- the optimized parameters.

Comment: @tchakravarty but they are not the same: `model_Nile$optim.out$par [1] -35.42932 -45.31288`.

Comment: Please show a reproducible example. On my machine with KFAS version 1.2.4, they are exactly the same.

Comment: It seems to be some kind of numerical issue with different versions of KFAS. Works beautifully on R-Fiddle: http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=GDbDp5LC

Comment: I would raise an issue about this on the package author's GH page: https://github.com/helske/KFAS